# More records in Right hand side table in a Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
  Table_A                    Table_Audit
  Id    Name               Id    Table_A_Id     Event           Date   
   1     A                 1          1          Cancelled     20-01-2014
   2     B                 2          1          Renewed       21-01-2014
                           3          1          Cancelled     22-01-2014
```

Table has a Audit table. As you can see there are more than one Cancel events against Table_A_Id. I want to Join Table_A with Audit to Get the Highest Cancelled date.

```
  SELECT TA.*,A.Date FROM Table_A TA
  LEFT JOIN Audit A
  On TA.Id = A.Table_A_Id AND A.Event ='Cancelled'
```

Can anyone suggest me how this can be amended to get the highest Cancelled date

Comment: Well, give it a try and see

Comment: Can you give an example of what the results should look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to pull the maximum date from the audit table, do the aggregation first and then the join:

```
SELECT TA.*, A.MAXDate
FROM Table_A TA LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT A.Table_A_Id, MAX(A.DATE) as MAXDATE
      FROM Audit A
      WHERE A.Event = 'Cancelled'
      GROUP BY A.Table_A_Id 
     ) A
     On TA.Id = A.Table_A_Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that There always exists entries in Table_A, which are linked to Table_Audit, but not always the other way around?
In that case, a left join is most likely prefered to a right join.

An example using temporary tables in MS-SQL:

```
declare @TABLE_A table(
ID int
, Name varchar(8)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE_A (ID, Name)
select 1, 'A'
union all
select 2, 'B'

declare @Table_Audit table(
ID int
, Table_A_Id int
, "Event" varchar(16)
, "Date" date
)

insert into @Table_Audit (ID, Table_A_Id, "Event", "Date")
select 1, 1, 'Cancelled', '2014-01-20'
union all
select 2, 1, 'Renewed', '2014-01-21'
union all
select 3, 1, 'Cancelled', '2014-01-22'


select
  a.ID
, a.Name
, ta.Date
from @TABLE_A a
left join @Table_Audit ta on ta.Table_A_Id = a.ID
where 1=1
and ta.Event = 'Cancelled'
and ta.Date = (select max(tai.Date)
               from @Table_Audit tai
               where tai.Event = 'Cancelled'
               and tai.Table_A_Id = ta.Table_A_Id
)
```

Comment: Complicated answer ... probably too complicated for the OP given the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think GROUP BY and MAX should do the trick.

```
SELECT TA.*, A.MaxDate
FROM Table_A TA
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT Table_A_ID, Event, MAX(Date) MaxDate
                FROM Table_Audit 
                WHERE Event = 'Cancelled' 
                GROUP BY Table_A_ID, Event) A
        ON TA.Id = A.Table_A_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will get you the maximum ID for each event type and table and display all the audits for them.

```
SELECT ta.*, t.Name
FROM Table_Audit ta
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Table_A_Id, Event, Max(ID) as maxId
             FROM Table_Audit
             GROUP BY Table_A_Id, Event
            ) maxAudits
      ON maxAudits.maxId = ta.ID
INNER JOIN Table_A t on t.Id = ta.Table_A_Id
```

Comment: This is very close but has one problem: cancelling date is missing on the result.

Comment: @daniloquio Is cancelling date in the Table_Audit table ?

Comment: Yes, the last column. The OP is using this field in the output clause. In my answer I use this date field with the MAX function and that works.

Comment: @daniloquio My English sarcasm didn't come accross.... "ta.*" returns all fields in the Table_Audit table including "Date". My answer therefore does return the date.

Comment: Wow, I see. You're not using Table_A at all. The op uses the alias TA for Table_A while you use it to the Table_Audit. Why are you joining Table_Audit with itself, I don't follow :S

Comment: Additionally, your result won't include Table Name; the OP is requesting that field in the output.

Comment: @daniloquio the sub-select produces the maximum audit events by audit event type with their Id. This has been joined back into the Table_Audit table to get all the other information the OP wanted. Point taken about Table Name. Added in.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 TA.*,A.Date FROM Table_A TA
INNER JOIN Audit A On TA.Id = A.Table_A_Id AND A.Event ='Cancelled'  ORDER BY DATE DESC
```